# which group did you put these gems in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

i noticed some people puts rspec-rails to development group, some puts it in development and test group, why?
and for these common gems,

```
gem 'faker'
gem 'populator'
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'factory_girl_rails'
gem 'guard-spork'
gem 'guard-rspec'
gem 'spork-rails'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'database_cleaner'
gem 'email_spec'
gem 'pry-rails'
```

which group do you put and the reason is ?

is there any clear guides about this?

for example, i only put 'pry-rails' in development group, because i don't need to load it in test group, i use it only for debugging something in development

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them exactly where you need them.

Most of those are test-related gems and as such should be loaded just into the `test` group, but some (such as factory_girl, faker and pry-rails) may also be useful in the `development` group – for example, you could use FactoryGirl to populate a fake development environment.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can define shared groups like this:

```
group :development, :test do
 #gems required in both env, like faker, factory girl, pry
end

group :development do
 #gems required only in dev like better_errors
end

group :test do
 #gems required only in test like capybara, rspec...
end
```